# My for loop for a matrix is not working

Tags: matlab, debugging, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix `[1 2 3 5;1 3 4 5]`.
Each row represents a path and each column represents the nodes of that path.
For example: for row `1` : `1-2-3-5` is a path with nodes `1`, `2` ,`3`, `5` (where `1` is the start node and `5` is the end node).
I want to consider an arc and arcs following that arc.
For example: I want to consider `(1,2)` and `(2-3)` and assign a cost to it.

I wrote a code but its showing an error.

```
for kkp = 1:size(R{ip},1) % R{ip} is my path matrix
    for jjp = 1:size(R{ip},2)-1
        for iip = 1:size (R{ip,2} -2)
            up = R{ip}(kkp,jjp);
            vp = R{ip}(kkp,jjp+1);
            wp =  R{ip}(kkp,jjp+2);
            cost1 = wt(up,vp); %wt(i,j) is a cost matrix that i already inputed.
            cost 2 = wt(vp,wp);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: You don't need three nested loops! Loop over the outer index (number of paths, `ip`) from 1 to numel(R), the inner loop (kkp) from 1 to numel(R{ip})-2, then set iip=kkp+1, jjp=kkp+2, and calculate path cost as you did. And fix the space in `cost 2 = ...`

Answer (score 3):

Line `3` of the code in your question is either a typo or your issue:

```
for iip = 1:size (R{ip,2} -2)
```

Should be

```
for iip = 1:size(R{ip},2) -2
```

Additionally, you never use `iip`. So maybe line `6` in your example should be:

```
wp =  R{ip}(kkp,iip+2);
```

Comment: I've made the correction but it is still showing an error. My cost2 outpput is coming as zero but that is not right.

my wt matrix is :

wt =[0 2 4 0;1 0 5 3;4 5 0 5;0 3 5 0];
so if for path 1-2-3-4 cost1 should be 2 and cost2 should be 5 (for 2-3) and 5 (for 3-4) .

Comment: Can you turn your question into a [short, self contained, correct, exmaple](http://sscce.org/)? These debugging questions tend to get out of hand quickly, because you don't show your entire code, so it remains entirely unclear what is **really** happening. For example, here, we are left to guess the values of `up`, `yp`, `wp`, we don't know the cell `R` - all of this could potentially be of interest.

Comment: @abc : see my comment above, but also: do you get an actual matlab `error message` - or just not the result you were expecting?